# Why this code has memory leakage?

Tags: c++, pointers, dynamic, memory-leaks

I checked every line but couldn't find where I forget to delete. I find `AllocateDynamicArray` and `FreeDynamicArray` code on this site and assume it's correct. I will provide valgrind output asap. Any help will be appreciated.

```
template <typename T>
T **AllocateDynamicArray(int nRows, int nCols) {
    T **dynamicArray;

    dynamicArray = new T*[nRows];
    for (int i = 0; i < nRows; i++) {
        dynamicArray[i] = new T [nCols];
        for (int j = 0; j < nCols; j++) {
            dynamicArray[i][j] = 0;
        }
    }
    return dynamicArray;
}


template <typename T>
void FreeDynamicArray(T** dArray, int nRows) {
    for (int i = 0; i < nRows; i++) {
        delete[] dArray[i];
    }
    delete[] dArray;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

    int numOfComps = 1;
    int** input = AllocateDynamicArray<int>(rowNo, 4);
    while (calculateAvgTime(false) > maxAvgTime) {
        numOfComps++;
    }
    FreeDynamicArray(input, rowNo);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}


double calculateAvgTime(bool print) {
    double waitingTime = 0;
    int* computers = new int[numOfComps];
    for (int i = 0; i < numOfComps; i++) {
        computers[i] = 0;
    }
    int** infoList = AllocateDynamicArray<int>(numOfComps, 2);

    //some code related to computers and infoList

    double waitingTime /= (double) (rowNo);
    FreeDynamicArray(infoList, numOfComps);
    delete[] computers;
    return waitingTime;
}
```

The following is the output of valgrind.

```
==21109== 
==21109== HEAP SUMMARY:
==21109==     in use at exit: 1,344 bytes in 4 blocks
==21109==   total heap usage: 72 allocs, 68 frees, 11,752 bytes allocated
==21109== 
==21109== 336 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 1 of 2
==21109==    at 0x4C28D27: operator new[](unsigned long) (in /usr/lib64/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==21109==    by 0x402159: Heap::Heap(int) (in /home/cs/c_turhan/bin/HW3/simulator/simulator)
==21109==    by 0x401977: calculateAvgTime(bool) (in /home/cs/c_turhan/bin/HW3/simulator/simulator)
==21109==    by 0x401792: main (in /home/cs/c_turhan/bin/HW3/simulator/simulator)
==21109== 
==21109== 1,008 bytes in 3 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 2 of 2
==21109==    at 0x4C28D27: operator new[](unsigned long) (in /usr/lib64/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==21109==    by 0x402159: Heap::Heap(int) (in /home/cs/c_turhan/bin/HW3/simulator/simulator)
==21109==    by 0x401977: calculateAvgTime(bool) (in /home/cs/c_turhan/bin/HW3/simulator/simulator)
==21109==    by 0x401724: main (in /home/cs/c_turhan/bin/HW3/simulator/simulator)
==21109== 
==21109== LEAK SUMMARY:
==21109==    definitely lost: 1,344 bytes in 4 blocks
==21109==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==21109==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==21109==    still reachable: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==21109==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==21109== 
==21109== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==21109== ERROR SUMMARY: 2 errors from 2 contexts (suppressed: 6 from 6)
```

Comment: Your code has memory leakage, because you use manual memory management. Don't do that. You are programming in c++, so use RAII to manage resources. Since you use dynamic arrays `std::vector<T>` is what you should use

Comment: How can I use RAII? Any tips?

Comment: Why do you think you have memory leaks? Quote what your memory-leak tool tells you. We're still waiting for the Valgrind output you promised. Doesn't the tool tell you where the leaked memory was allocated?

Comment: I realized the mistake is not because of the code I posted above therefore problem solved. Thanks.

Comment: The leak is not in the posted code; once I fix the syntax errors, it runs cleanly in valgrind. As we can see from the backtrace, the leaks come from a class called `Heap`, which isn't involved in the posted code. Perhaps you could post a test case that demonstrates the leak.

Comment: @CihadTurhan: As I said use `std::vector<T>`. Also look at [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization) for what RAII means.

Comment: Voted to close as **not a real question** because, as admitted, the posted code does not demonstrate the reported problem. The posted code doesn't even compile (duplicate definitions of `waitingTime`, for one).

Answer (score 5):

In `calculateAvgTime`, you allocate an array in `computers`, but you only free a single item. Use `delete[]` whenever you use `new[]`.

Better yet, just use a `vector` and watch the memory-manage issues of this program disappear.

Comment: For pointers of simple types, e.g. 'int', 'char', 'short', delete without [] is fine.

Comment: @ciphor: No its not. It is UB as per standard and will crash on quite some implementations.

Comment: Thanks for reminding the missing brackets, I corrected but it still has memory leakages.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not seeing where 'rowNo' is defined, so there might be a problem with "FreeDynamicArray()" not deleting all of the memory, also if you are using VS try getting visual leak detector ([here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9815/Visual-Leak-Detector-Enhanced-Memory-Leak-Detectio)), it will help you track down what memory is being leaked and help you pinpoint the error.